# AngularJs ng-repeat change loop increment

Tags: angularjs

I'm newbie to AngularJs. I want to use ng-repeat as for(i=0; i < ele.length; i+=2)

I have a table with 4 columns, where I'm going to use ng-repeat

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="i in elements">
   <th>{{i.T}}</th>
   <td>{{i.V}}</td>
   <th>{{elements[($index+1)].T}}</th> <!-- This should be next element of the elements array -->
   <td>{{elements[($index+1)].V}}</td> <!-- This should be next element of the elements array -->
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to access 2 elements in a single iteration and iteration increment should be 2

I hope this make sense. Please help me.

Please check this html view [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PSwPWqKwqp0vzFJTO8eh?p=preview)

Comment: will you be ok if the model object is changed?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, you mean rearrange the elements of the array?. I'm getting that array from a API request and use it many other places. So have few issues when modifying for ng-repeat

Comment: A solution is to use filter as given in http://jsfiddle.net/gwfPh/

Comment: You should still change the model, even if it's coming from an API. You just need to convert it to what you need before passing it to the $scope. It would make more sense.

Comment: @G45 even if the data is from an API, once you fetch the data from the external source you can make changes

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Thanks for the jsfiddle example. that worked for me. I used filter to remove 2 elements from array in each iteration.

Comment: @G45 can you post your solution as an answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Sorry I was too quick to figure out it works, but it doesn't. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a filter that creates an even copy of the array:

```
.filter("myFilter", function(){
    return function(input, test){
        var newArray = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < input.length; x+=2){
             newArray.push(input[x]);   
        }
        return newArray;
    }
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwfPh/15/

Comment: Thanks @Mathew, It is not working accurately. If you can see in your JsFiddle example's resulting view, the 2nd row is wrong. Other that it is ok. I tried to figure out what is the glitch there but no luck.

Comment: What about edge cases? i.e. when input is empty array or length is an odd number

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you want to walk your list and alternate th and td's while iterating.
If so you could use a ng-switch:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="i in elements" ng-switch on="$index % 2">
    <th ng-switch-when="0">{{i.T}}</th> 
    <td ng-switch-when="1">{{i.V}}</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

[See Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/38aNNcHaaO2B9hv1Nvty)

Comment: Thanks @Sebastien But my requirement is bit different. Please check this Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/PSwPWqKwqp0vzFJTO8eh?p=preview. This should be my resulting view.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of involves a change in the data model

Template

```
<table ng-app="test-app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
<tr ng-repeat="i in items">

   <th>{{i.T1}}</th>
   <td>{{i.V1}}</td>
   <th>{{i.T2}}</th>
   <td>{{i.V2}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
testApp.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var elements=[]; //This is the dynamic values loaded from server
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        elements.push({
            T : i,
            V : 'v' + i
        });
    }

    //A converter which convert the data elements to a format we can use
    var items = [];
    var x = Math.ceil(elements.length / 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        var index = i * 2;
        var obj = {
            T1 : elements[index].T,
            V1 : elements[index].V
        }
        if (elements[index + 1]) {
            obj.T2 = elements[index + 1].T;
            obj.V2 = elements[index + 1].V
        }
        items.push(obj)
    }

    $scope.items = items;

}]);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dfN2G/2/)

Another slightly different approach can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dfN2G/3/).